# Using postgres EXISTS on same table as parent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm interested in querying a PostgreSQL 8.4 table to list rows which, for a given row, if it has any adjacent children with a particular field value.

A simple example would be a task list, where tasks can have child tasks, which are adjacent rows in the same table related by a `parent_id` column. I'd like to write a query that lists top-level tasks and bubbles up the status of child tasks. In plain English, "List the `status` field for each task row, considering each row's children, if there are any children whose status is not 'closed'." One-level deep child relationship consideration is fine — no need to recurse.

Here's what I've come up with so far, but I'm getting zero results even when I'm sure there are rows that meet the criteria:

```
SELECT id, summary, created_at
FROM tasks
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT summary
        FROM tasks
        WHERE parent_id=tasks.id
            AND status != 'closed'
    )
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Use an alias `FROM tasks t ....(... WHERE t.parent_id= .. AND t.status)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that your sub-select is executed first:

```
    SELECT summary
    FROM tasks
    WHERE parent_id=tasks.id
        AND status != 'closed'
```

Your `parent_id=tasks.id` is a red herring. It *looks* like you're comparing across tables, but you're not--you're checking every row, where tasks.parent_id=tasks.id (since there's only one table here).  And that naturally means 0 rows.

So you need to disambiguate:

```
SELECT id, summary, created_at
FROM tasks AS parent_tasks
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT summary
        FROM tasks AS child_tasks
        WHERE parent_tasks.parent_id=child_tasks.id
            AND status != 'closed'
    )
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```